# Redraw issue with NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

Hi I have a weird redraw issue with the `NumericUpDown` control. If I have another control at the same location and set its `Visible` property to `false` and the `Visible` property of the `NumericUpDown` to `true` the `NumericUpDown` appears without a border and parts of the other control are visible in the background (even if its `Visible` property is `false`). Even a call to `Refresh` of the `NumericUpDown` or the parent container won't change anything. If the control that is in the background is a `TextBox` the `NumericUpDown` appears correctly but I assume this is the case cause the border is equal and therefore it only looks like it's drawn correctly.

Is this a bug of the `NumericUpDown` control? How can I fix it?

Thanks for help.

Edit: Here is a screenshot. I simply change the visible properties of the `ComboBox` and the `NumericUpDown` dependent of the `Checked` properties of the `RadioButtons`.

[image]

Comment: Can you prepare a complete small program to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Added a screenshot. I'll create an example.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this with a simple example. In a simple winforms application it works correctly. In the bugged case the controls are located inside a `GroupBox` which is located inside of a `UserControl` which is then added into a `Panel` or `Form` at a different time. But I didn't have any drawing issues so far. I noticed that the border is never drawn. Even if there was no control before the `NumericUpDown` is drawn without a border and also without the white background. It looks like a label with the up and down buttons. Don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Didn't my answer help you?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. :(

Comment: I tested to hide all controls in the `GroupBox`, setting the border style for the `NumericUpDown`, invalidated it and then set the `Visible` property to `true`. It appears without any border or background.

Comment: @RobertS. can't you record the screen an upload the video of problem?

Comment: Sorry I'm not allowed to show the software I'm working on so I can't do this. But basically it is just what you can see in the screenshot above. The control isn't redrawn correctly.

Comment: As a note: All `NumericUpDown` controls are affected in the dialog, even those which are part of a `UserControl` I dropped from the toolbox. But the `NumericUpDown` controls appear correctly inside the designer.

Comment: I also tested to draw something inside of the `Paint` event of the `NumericUpDown`. The event is fired but I can't draw anything. It just does not appear.

Comment: The panel that contains the `NumericUpDown` is a property of a class that I dynamically load by its assembly during the application runs. Maybe this could be the problem. I assume that the `NumericUpDown` is not initialized correctly this way. It seems to need `BeginInit` and `EndInit` in the `InitializeComponent` method. I guess their is some bug when working with external assemblies which contains `UserControls`.

Comment: @RobertS. good news, i found your problem, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I used an overlay control from CodeProject which allows me to draw primitives over my entire form. Despite the fact I only use it rarely it will still change the way child controls are painted. While other controls work fine, the `NumericUpDown` seems to have some problems with it.

Maybe someone will have the same issue in the future. Therefore here is the link to the CodeProject project I use: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26071/Draw-Over-WinForms-Controls.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    p.Height = 200;
    p.Width = 200;
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    Controls.Add(p);
    NumericUpDown nud = new NumericUpDown();
    nud.Location = new Point(150, 150);
    nud.Height = 100;
    nud.Width = 100;
    Controls.Add(nud);
    nud.BringToFront();
}
```

for your code just add:

```
numericUpDown1.BringToFront();
```

the problem is because you have added a numericUpdown to your panel but it's not completely inside the panel and you must bring it to front to see complete view of numericupdown.

you can do this even without code. just do as in the pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

please let me know if you get your answer.

Comment: Thanks but nothing has changed. The border is set to `Fixed3D` at the beginning. Changing it before setting the `Visible` property has no effect. The border is not drawn at all.

Comment: Hello Riddle. Thank you for your efforts but unfortunately the `BringToFront` doesn't work either. The control is drawn (also in front already) but only partial. The border is missing despite the fact that the border style is set. The `GroupBox` where the control is located is much bigger than in my screenshot so this won't be the problem.

Comment: @RobertS. it was the only way i could imagine your problem and solve, i think other part of your code is effecting this. because it works fine for me and you can test numeric updown in a new project and see it works.

Comment: Hi Riddle. I really appreciate your efforts. That's why I upvoted your answer. I found the problem myself and you couldn't know the reason as a third party component caused this. So I'm sorry to waste your time with this. Thank you again.

Comment: @RobertS. No, i'm sorry i should have tried harder.